# How to create a performance counter and see it in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell-2.0

Hello I want to create a performance counter named as *FileCopierApp*, this should work with the get-counter cmdlet, How can I Achieve this? the properties would be:

```
CounterSetName : FileCopierApp
MachineName : .
CounterSetType : SingleInstance
Description : Statistics for FileCopierApp.exe application
Paths : {\localhost\blablabla}
PathWithInstances : {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you want to add your own performance counters to your application and have them show up in powershell. Take a look at:

http://www.codeplex.com/PerfmonCounterHelper

It allows you to easily add performance counters to your application, which will automatically show up in powershell's get-counter cmdlet.

-Oisin